# What is a band box?

Tags: phrases

> She looks like she just stepped out of a band box.

In this sentence, what does "stepped out of a band box" mean?

Comment: Just stepped out of a bandbox... *a person looking as if he had just stepped out of a bandbox was neat, spruce and spotless.* https://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/5/messages/847.html

Comment: Depending on tone, it means smooth and crisp, or stuffy and prissy.

Comment: It's a metaphor. A band box is a case that holds clothes neatly. So if you look like you came out of it, you're neat like the those clothes.

Comment: @Barmar That looks remarkably like an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The big white collars that were worn in the 17th century were called 'bands', as the two strips hanging from a neckband that some clergy and lawyers wear still are. A bandbox was for keeping such collars clean and uncrumpled. Later, the term was used for hat boxes. So, something that had just come out of a bandbox was fresh and smart-looking.